# How to edit Wordpress menu to make a two-line menu?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

I am trying to edit my wordpress page to make every menu item at the top of the page two lines long with the top line being a single word (ie: Home, About, etc.) and another line in a different font underneath each item (ie: "Read about us" underneath "About").

Here is an example of what I mean:
http://images.sixrevisions.com/2009/04/13-26_css_block_menu.png

I am aware that this is achieved in some way by using the 'Description' box on the Wordpress menu screen, and I have checked the 'show descriptions' box, but I'm unable to get it to display correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by creating a custom walker which extends the Walker_Nav_Menu class - here's a good tutorial on it;

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output